# Google Script import txt files from Google Drive

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, setvalue

so I'm trying to write a script to import text files, based on the file names, and the tab names.

The txt files are game server log extracts, 3 different types of logs.

I have managed to get the script to import the text based on the file names (types), but having issues running some simple formatting at the end of a loop before moving to the next type or log.

Basically, the script imports all the text from the log files parses it as a CSV and dumps it to the sheet. The sheet removes duplicates, splits the text into columns etc, they should move on to the next type of log (and switch tab) - repeat.

I'm still picking scripting up so please be gentle....! Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function ImportAll() {
var folderID = "my google drive foler"
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var ss, sRow, lRow, fRow, csvData, logFile, file, sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var data = [];
var logType = ["admin_", "kill_", "login_"]
var allSheets = ['Admin', 'Kill', 'Login']


for (var k = 0; k < logType.length; k++) {
  var files = folder.searchFiles('title contains "' + logType[k] + '"');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();   
    data.push(file.getName())
  };
  ss = sheet.getSheetByName(allsheets[k])
  sRow = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1;
  //Browser.msgBox(data[0])
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    logFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(data[i]).next();
    csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(logFile.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    fRow = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1;
    ss.getRange(fRow, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  };
  lRow = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  ss.getRange('A' + sRow + ':A' + lRow).removeDuplicates().activate();  
  ss.getRange('A' + sRow + ':A' + lRow).splitTextToColumns('-');
  ss.getRange('B' + sRow + ':B' + lRow).splitTextToColumns(':');
  ss.getRange('B:B').setNumberFormat('HH:mm:ss');
  ss.getFilter().remove();
  ss.getRange('A1:E' + lRow).createFilter();

  var rng = sheet.getRange('D2:D' + lRow)
  var rngV = rng.getValues();
  var String = "";    

  for(var i=0;i<rngV.length;i++)
  {
    String = rngV[i].toString().replace(s, '')
    rngV[i] = String // is working 
  }

  rng.setValues(rngV)  // NOT WORKING!!!!!!

  //sheet.appendRow(data); //throws [L]JavaLang@****
}

};
}
```

I keep getting thrown "TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null." errors, and I've tried a heap of different things to no avail.

Comment: Please review the Execution transcript and copy the last line "Execution failed..." into your question. This will supply the complete error messages as well as the line number on which execution failed.

Comment: As @Tedinoz said, we need your execution transcript for debugging it. You can get them from `View > Execution transcripts` after you run the function. We tried to run your code to reproduce your error, but we found other issues non related to the original one: (1) Line 18: must be `ss = sheet.getSheetByName(allSheets[k]);` (2) Line 42: should be `String = rngV[i].toString().replace('s', '');` (3) Line 52: that brace is not needed. Please, provide the requested logs and/or the minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better.